# Get the values from Dynamically created select box in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have written some code for getting the value from dynamic select box using JavaScript.

Below is the code:

```
function getCategory(categoryval) {
    var category = categoryval;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "childinfo.html?method=getCategory",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {

            var result = $.parseJSON(response);

            for (var j = 0; j < result.parentVOList.length; j++) {
                $(category)
                    .append(
                    '<option value="' + result.parentVOList[j].classStreamID + '">' + result.parentVOList[j].category + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
}
var tt = document.getElementById("userRecords");
var tr2 = document.createElement("tr");
var td_stream = document.createElement("td");
var addtxt2 = document.createElement("select");

addtxt2.name = "stream";
addtxt2.id = "stream" ;
addtxt2.setAttribute("class", "stream");
getCategory(".stream");
td_stream.appendChild(addtxt2);
tr2.appendChild(td_stream);
tt.appendChild(tr2);
var pramoteBtn_tr1 = document.createElement("tr"); //Creating TR Tag for header
var pramoteBtn_td1 = document.createElement("td"); // Creating First TD
var br = document.createElement("br");
tt.appendChild(br);

var pramoteBtn = document.createElement("input");
pramoteBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
pramoteBtn.setAttribute("value", "Pramote");
pramoteBtn.setAttribute("name", "pramote");
pramoteBtn.setAttribute("class", "pramote");

pramoteBtn_td1.appendChild(pramoteBtn);
pramoteBtn_tr1.appendChild(pramoteBtn_td1);
tt.appendChild(pramoteBtn_tr1);
```

When I click on Pramote button I want stream value.

So am written some code:

```
$('#userRecords').delegate(".pramote","click",function(){
    var value=[];
    value=$("#userRecords.stream").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

But when I click on Pramote button value is coming `undefined`
Please give me any solution for getting the stream value.

Comment: `value=$("#userRecords .stream").val();` ??? You'd have better to post rendered HTML code instead of this unreadable js snippet

Comment: Please can you copy/past the generated HTML

Comment: Wait, you use jQuery and managed to come up with something as terrible as your creatElement spaghetti code?

Comment: `addtxt2.id = "stream"+i ;` where's the `i` coming from?

Comment: @iMoses i is not require

Comment: The code you are presenting will result in an error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`) and even if for some reason `i` was initialized in the global scope, you'll never truly know the `id` of your `select` element, so why is it there?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide your html, i can't tell how to make it. But i would do it like this:

```
var currentVal = 0;
function addOption(categoryId) {
    $('#wrapper #' + categoryId).append('<option value="' + (currentVal++) + '">Some text</option>');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.promote', function(){
       var values = [];
       $.each($('select option:selected'), function(){
           values.push($(this).val());
       }

       console.log(values);
   }
});

<div id="#wrapper"></div>
```

With `addOption` function you add some option to specified category, and after clicking `.promote`, you collect all selected values.